# How do I get Rails 4.x streaming to work with MySQL when testing?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I created a new Rails 4.2.1 test project to try out the new streaming feature (the 'Live' one which I read about [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/streaming-with-rails-4/)). This project is set up to use MySQL for the database (I also tried Sqlite but couldn't repro the issue with it). The project is simple, consisting only of: 1) a model `Test` with 2 attributes (both strings). 2) a simple route `resources :tests` and 3) a simple controller `tests_controller` with one action `index`. The model and controller were generated by the standard rails generators, and only the controller was modified, as follows:

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Live

  def index
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    response.stream.write('{"count": 5, "tests": [')
    Test.find_each do |test|
      response.stream.write(test.to_json)
      response.stream.write(',')
    end
    response.stream.write(']}')
    response.stream.close
  end
end
```

When I run `rails s` and test by hand everything seems fine. But when I added a test (shown below) I get a strange error:

`1) Error:
TestsControllerTest#test_index:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: This connection is in use by: #<Thread:0x007f862a4a7e48@/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/live.rb:269 sleep>: ROLLBACK`

The test is:

```
require 'test_helper'

class TestsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "index" do
    @request.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Note that the error is intermittent, coming up only about half the time. Also, even though testing by hand doesn't cause any errors I'm worried that when multiple clients hit the API at the same time that errors will occur. Any suggestions as to what's going on here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have the same error in my tests :(

Comment: @piton4eg I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: i don't know will it help your or not, but in my case i fixed it by adding check on count records. In your case it will looks like:

    if Test.count > 0
      response.stream.write('{"count": 5, "tests": [')
      Test.find_each do |test|
        response.stream.write(test.to_json)
        response.stream.write(',')
      end
      response.stream.write(']}')
    end

Comment: also, maybe it will help you https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20223

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old, but you need to actually checkout a new database connection since `ActionController::Live` executes the action in a new thread:

> The final caveat is that your actions are executed in a separate thread than the main thread. Make sure your actions are thread safe, and this shouldn't be a problem (don't share state across threads, etc).

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/861b70e92f4a1fc0e465ffcf2ee62680519c8f6f/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/live.rb

You can even use an `around_filter`/`around_action` for this.